# Create a simple booking system using Jquery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I'm building a simple booking system for a friend's holiday house and I'm really struggling to implement it. Only one group can stay in the cottage at one time. First let me run through what the booking system must be able to do (things I've already completed are in brackets).

- Receive emails from guests with the dates they want to stay
  (completed but haven't included as not relevant).
- Admin can then choose those dates in Jquery UI datepicker and
  store the fromDate and toDate in the database (completed but not
  sure if correct).
- The fromDate and toDate are then retrieved from the database and then
  disabled in the Jquery UI datepicker (Don't know how to do this).
- When the fromDate and toDate are disabled all the dates in between
  those dates should be disabled, with the fromDate and toDate in a
  slightly different colour to indicate the check in and check out
  times (No idea how to do this).
- The admin should be able to edit and delete dates stored in the
  database. No need for taking payment as  this will be handled
  offline.

Ok, I'm going to paste in all the code that I have completed so far. I used includes in my file but I will post each file separately here in the order they appear. The most important ones, where all the action is happening are calendar.php and datepicker-admin.js but I've posted everything for context. I really am gazzumped here so if someone could walk me through a solution and help me understand what's going on I would really appreciate it. I took on this project because I thought it would be a good way to learn PHP but I'm a little over my head.

**config.php**

```
<?php

    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_NAME", "calendar");
    define("DB_PORT", "XXXX"); // Not going to display my port online
    define("DB_USER", "db_user");
    define("DB_PASS", "db_password");
```

**database.php**

```
<?php  

require('config.php');
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";port=" . DB_PORT,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not connect to the database";
    exit;
}
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

  <title>Sticky Footer Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


  <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

      <!-- Wrap all page content here -->
      <div id="wrap">

        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Muscheltraum</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!--container-->
        </div><!--navbar-->
```

**calendar.php**

```
<?php 
    require('inc/header.php');
    require('database.php');

// a request method of post indicates that
// we are receiving a form submission
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $fromDate = trim($_POST["fromDate"]);
    $toDate = trim($_POST["toDate"]);

    if  ($fromDate == "") {
        $error_message = "You must select a from date";
    }

    if  ($toDate == "") {
        $error_message = "You must select a to date";
    }
    else { 

        try { 

            $results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO availability (fromDate, toDate) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $results->bindParam(1, $fromDate);
            $results->bindParam(2, $toDate);
            $results->execute();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Data could not be inserted.";
            exit;
        }


        header("Location: " . "calendar.php/?status=thanks");

    }

}

        try { 
                $results = $db->prepare("SELECT fromDate, toDate FROM availability");
                $results->execute();

                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "Data could not be retrieved.";
                    exit;
                }

                $disablethese = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "thanks") { ?>
                 <p class="alert alert-success">Successful!</p>
                 <?php } else { ?>

                <?php
                if (isset($error_message)) {
                    echo '<p class="alert alert-danger">' . $error_message . '</p>';
                }

                } ?>

                <form action="calendar.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fromDate">From</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" data-disablethese="<?=json_encode($disablethese)?>">
                        <?php echo '<pre>';
                              var_dump($disablethese);
                              ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="toDate">To</label>
                        <input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate"></input>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php require('inc/footer.php');?>
```

**footer.php**

```
</div><!--endwrap-->
  <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted credit">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
  </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core Javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datepicker-admin.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**datepicker-admin.js**

```
var disablethese = $("#fromDate").data("disablethese");
console.log(disablethese);
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [disablethese.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
});
```

This is what my table looks like at the moment. It only has one row at the moment. id: 10 fromDate: 2014-02-28 toDate: 2014-02-23

[image: database table]

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No console errors or anything coming up in the PHP logs

Comment: I can see you have an exclamation on your DB connection     `define("DB_HOST", "localhost!");` try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: That is there accidentally because I was using exclamation marks to hide my username and password, I must have accidentally put it there. My problem is not error messages, I'm just a little lost and need a map to point me in the right direction to figure this out.